# Regex calculating from right to left

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have added regex in PHP wordpress rewrite code

```
(.*)-newfoundland-and-labrador-([^\/-]*)-(.*)$
```

I am matching following string with this

```
privatelisting-newfoundland-and-labrador-chevrolet-cobalt
```

I am expecting following as matched parameters

```
1.  `privatelisting`
2.  `chevrolet`
3.  `cobalt`
```

But I am getting following

```
1. `privatelisting`
2. `and`
3. `labrador-chevrolet-cobalt-asdasd`
```

its look like regex is executing  it right to left.

Wordpress it look like

```
$newrules['car-ads/(.*?)-newfoundland-and-labrador-([^\/-]*?)-(.*?)$'] = 'index.php?pagename=car-search&city=$matches[1]&province=newfoundland and labrador&make=$matches[2]&model=$matches[3]';
```

Please help.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bG2zB0/1 Working fine for me

Comment: here it is working fine, but in code it is executing it from right to left

Comment: got it  I have rule (.*)-newfoundland-and-labrador-([^\/-]*)-(.*)$ above my rule so it was getting overwriiten.